# Retrieving .data('value') from <select> "sometimes" works

Tags: php, jquery, html-select

My select box that is generated by PHP:

```
<select>
    <option selected>Select something</option>
    <option data-value="test"></option>
</select>
```

So far I have tried the following ways to retrieve the value within the data-value attribute:

```
$('select').children(":selected").data('value');
$('select option:selected').data('value')
$('select option:selected').attr('data-value');
$('select').find(':selected').data('value');
```

Of course there are a couple of more ways to do this. Once the one of these options gets executed I "sometimes" get the value within the data-value attribute. Even using

```
$('select').on('change', function () { // code });
```

gives me the same result. Am I missing some underlying thing?

**FIXED:**

After every select I use the data information for something else. Then I refresh the select box data by retrieving the remaining data information from the database. At that point I forgot to add the attribute data-value to every option..

Comment: What does it mean `sometimes`?

Comment: It means that around 50% of the times it returns "undefined" and for the other 50% i get the correct value.

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/zr6aaouv/) works fine. Maybe coz your `<option selected>Select something</option>` doesnt have any data variable

Comment: @CerlinBoss Same result though. This is getting really weird, the code is too simple to give me these unreliable results...

Comment: @MarijnvanGool : same results? how come? did you change anything?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5f05uj60/1/ - can you recreate the issue in the fiddle